# Unable to delete VMs in Azure AME tenant

Tags: azure, virtual-machines

All the VMs are stuck in the state Error code "NetworkingInternalOperationError" because the previous delete operation timed out and did not delete any resources. We are now unable to delete, I tried 'Reapply, 'Redeploy' but nothing helps. Kindly advise. Because this is AME tenant, is the only option of deleting is via Geneva Actions/OnebranchApprovalService ?

Comment: Redeploy only works when the VM is started, same for reapply. Are the VMs fully stopped and deallocated before you tried to delete them?

Answer (score 0):

You could try with PowerShell and then using -Force

```
# Forcefully remove the VM
Remove-AzVM -ResourceGroupName $resourceGroupName -Name $vmName -Force
```